# Which tool can replace RFT and Selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium, functional-testing, rft

I want to automate testing of java based applications, not exactly portals though.
RFT 7 version that we have is not compatible with latest version of Firefox, so we need another tool, preferably open source.

Please suggest some replacement for Selenium and RFT. The purpose is automation of Functional testing.

Comment: What features do you need which selenium does not have?

Comment: TestProject is 1 of the good candidates:  https://link.testproject.io/bsg

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant "Web applications", since that's what Selenium is for.

I suggest [Sahi Open Source](http://sahi.co.in/sahi-open-source/): works with many browsers, OS independent. I've never used it though, so can't give you a proper review.

Comment: You can use Sahi, Watir and latest one is TestProject.

Answer (score 0):

Both RFT (Rational Functional Tester) and Selenium is used for Functional & Regression test of web. RFT is commercial & Selenium is open source/free tool.

There are some other free tools that you can try. Such as

[TestProject](https://link.testproject.io/bsg)

[Sahi](https://sahipro.com/sahi-open-source/)

[Watir](http://watir.com/)